# Perform a working-directory-listing through electron app (angular5)

Tags: webpack, angular5, fs

I am trying to build a native app that performs a simple directory listing on the working directory. From what I've read till now you can import node `fs` module for such operations.

But `fs` is not directly accessible.

What I have done till now is:

`ng eject` so that I can manually edit webpack.

However I cannot really find the next step. I have tried adding:

```
module.exports = {
  "externals": {
      "fs": "require('fs')"
  },
```

but I still get: `ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(2,21): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'fs'`

when running: `webpack`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately `require()` is not available on angular components during build time.

It fails on with message:

> ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(5,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'

If I use this: `import * as fs from 'fs';`. I get build error:

> ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(5,21): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'fs'

If I use `import { remote } from 'electron';`, or `import { ipcRenderer } from 'electron';` I get a runtime error (when I try to reference any of the two inside the code):

> fs.existsSync is not a function
>       at `Object.<anonymous>`

A solution for accessing fs in both angular5/6 (without any modifications) is using this:

`const fs = (<any>window).require("fs");`

The following also works in case someone was to use `ipcRenderer`.

`const electron = (<any>window).require(electron);`
`electron.ipcRenderer.send(...)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to obtain list on renderer side you need to use remote module, no need to include fs in webpack, just do :

```
var remote = require('electron').remote;
var fs = remote.require('fs');
```

Otherwise you can use ipc channel to send desired folder to main process where search will be performed and listed files will be directed back to renderer process. Like so :

```
ipcMain.on("listDir", (event,folder) => fs.readdir(folder, ...))
```